# Is it possible to call lambda from another cross account lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Am using serverless framework am trying to access a cross account lambda from my lambda function am getting the following error

**User: arn:aws:sts::984589850232:assumed-role/device-service-sandbox-authenticateDevice-us-east-1-lambdaRole/device-service-sandbox-authenticateDevice is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:938718425371:function:cm-mgmt-service-sandbox-authenticateDevice because no resource-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action",**

I want to access without using sts assume role

This is the permission i have added in the lambda which am trying to access

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "addCrossAccountPermission",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:938718425371:function:cm-mgmt-service-sandbox-authenticateDevice",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "984589850232"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:984589850232:function:device-service-sandbox-authenticateDevice"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my code the invoking lambda written in serverless framework

```
let params = {
    FunctionName:
      "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:938718425371:function:cm-mgmt-service-sandbox-authenticateDevice",
    Payload: JSON.stringify({
      deviceid : "PNR04ESC1000002082"
    }),
  };

  const result = await awsWrapper.invokeLambda(params);


async function invokeLambda(params) {
  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region: process.env.region,
  });
  return lambda.invoke(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: The invoking Lambda function needs permission to invoke the cross-account function, and the invoked function needs to be [configured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) to allow that to happen.

Comment: The displayed policy will address the second requirement, but make sure the 'calling' function also has permission to call `Invoke()` on Lambda functions (either _all_ functions or at least the one you wish to call).

Comment: @jarmod I have made changes on my question i have added inovking function code as well, can you tell me where am making the mistake?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein how to make sure that my calling function has permission or not? Where do i need add that permission?

Comment: Not sure. This might help: [Using resource-based policies for AWS Lambda - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Lambda function 1 in account A to invoke Lambda function 2 in account B:

- Lambda function 1's IAM role must allow lambda:invokeFunction on the ARN of Lambda function 2
- Lambda function 2 must have a resource policy that allows account A to invoke it

In case it's not clear why the latter resource policy is required, IAM principals in account A cannot unilaterally give themselves permission to invoke Lambda functions (or, in general, to access AWS resources) in account B. Hopefully it's obvious why that is. Account B must explicitly allow account A.

Example of Lambda function 1's IAM policy, allowing cross-account invocation of function 2 in account B from function 1 in account A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "sid1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:BBBBBBBBBBBB:function:lambda-function-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of Lambda function 2's resource-based policy, allowing cross-account invocation of function 2 in account B from account A:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sid1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AAAAAAAAAAAA:root"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:BBBBBBBBBBBB:function:lambda-function-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the use of principal `arn:aws:iam::AAAAAAAAAAAA:root` in function 2's resource-based policy allows any IAM principal within account A to invoke Lambda function 2, as long as that IAM principal itself has invokeFunction permission on the function 2 ARN. If you want to restrict this permission so that only Lambda function 1 can invoke Lambda function 2 then you can change `arn:aws:iam::AAAAAAAAAAAA:root` to the ARN of Lambda function 1.

Comment: I have 2 queries 1) Where can i see that Example of Lambda function 1's IAM policy whether is it rightly added or not? 2) Can you see my principal key of my code which i have asked in question and check whether is it correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

As Jarmod mentioned above you need to add Resource Based policy in target lambda.

For Lambda **lambda-one** in account A to invoke Lambda **lambda-two** in account B, you need to perform following steps

1. **lambda-one** IAM role say **lambda-one-role** must allow **lambda:invokeFunction** on the ARN of **lambda-two**
2. **lambda-two** must have a resource policy that allows to invoke it from **lambda-one** of Account A

   Resource-based policy Principal will be : **arn:aws:iam::2128732178:role/lambda-one-role**
   where 2128732178 account id of Account A